# How can I use chewing(zhuyin) input method?

Tags: 18.04, input-method, chinese

I did install ibus-chewing by`sudo apt-get install ibus-chewing`, terminal told me it's been installed and is already the newest version, but I cannot find `chewing` in my input settings. How can I enable chewing or other zhuyin input methods?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate e.g. the `zh_TW.UTF-8` locale.

```
sudo locale-gen zh_TW.UTF-8
```

*Edit:*

This is rather confusing. I just submitted an issue to the GNOME developers:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/82

Comment: Thanks,  I was confused about I couldn't find `Chinese(Taiwan)` in the settings. This helps a lot!